# Issue with hover and touchend events in iOS devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, ios

There's a search bar on my website that dynamically loads search results based on user input. Next, when the use hovers over any of the search result, a data-url gets dynamically added to the search input field as shown below:

```
<input id="mainsearch" data-init-space="false" data-type="listen" data-listen-target="#mainsearchbtn" data-listen="state" type="search" results="16" class="main-search type-ahead form-control square color-gray-dark font-regular font-scaling-20 text-uppercase padding-left-30 ui-autocomplete-input ui-autocomplete-loading" placeholder="Search for..." autocomplete="off" data-url="/s/_XYZ">
```

Next, when user clicks that particular result, he's redirected to the respective page. Things work as expected in desktop.

The issue is, i want the user to be able to reach a particular page on the first tap of any search result in mobiles and tablets. Currently it happens on two taps.

This is what I tried doing:

```
iosDropdownClick: function(){
    $("body").on('touchend click',"ul.ui-menu li .ui-menu-item-wrapper", function(){
        var el = $("#mainsearch");
        var link = el.attr('data-url');
        window.location.href = link;
    });
}
```

However, this leads to an undefined page. Please help me with this issue.

Thanks :)

Comment: Is the URL in `data-url` correct ?

Comment: The actual value for the data-url that i have given here isn't the exact one. But that's the format in which it's given. @Jean-maximeBouloc